# cPanel/WHM IP Ban - How to Unban IP

Tags: linux, cpanel, whm

We are using htaccess basic authentication on one of our sites. One of our clients tried accessing the site and failed logging in multiple times. Now when visiting our site they simply get a "Can't Display Webpage" error.

I believe I've had this before and I believe there IP's got banned after so many failures. I'm not sure where to go in WHM/cPanel to unban them - appreciate any assistance!!

Thanks

Loren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to do this from within CPanel/WHM. Instead, you need root access to the server and you will need to SSH. It is probably the firewall which has blocked the user.

You need to remove the IP from the firewalls banned IP's list and restart the firewall. Optionally, you can then whitelist the users IP to prevent future issues.

EDIT: It looks like you might be able to do this from within WHM after all. Please see http://www.anysitesupport.com/cpanel-add-firewall-exception/

Comment: whitelisting an IP that has to be unbanned is like removing a door that has to be unlocked.  In terms of security concerns this is the biggest NO-NO possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've this matter with customers IPs banned after an email server migration.
Due password reset of some email accounts the customers can't login with pop3, imap, even the webmail was affected.

The ban is implemented in Cpanel for cPHulk, that prevents the brute force attempts.

The solution for me was Disable temporally the cPHulk Brute Force Protection, until all the customers set the correct password.

I hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

1st need to change your isp
then login whm and search cPHulk Brute Force Protection
and whitelist management and add your 1st  ip  address and click on add